# Can sqlite `order by` and `where` clause use the Index together

Tags: sql, sqlite, indexing, sql-order-by

Create a table

```
CREATE TABLE Shares(
    shareId TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    fromId INTEGER NOT NULL,
    toId INTEGER NOT NULL,
    time INTEGER NOT NULL);
```

And create the index

```
CREATE INDEX Shares_time_toId_fromId ON Shares(time, toId, fromId);
```

Then insert some rows

```
insert into Shares(shareId, fromId, toId, time) values(1,1,1,1);
insert into Shares(shareId, fromId, toId, time) values(2,2,2,2);
insert into Shares(shareId, fromId, toId, time) values(3,3,3,3);
insert into Shares(shareId, fromId, toId, time) values(4,3,3,4);
insert into Shares(shareId, fromId, toId, time) values(5,3,3,5);
```

use explain to show

```
explain select * from Shares where toId=3 and fromId=3 order by time desc;
```

the result is

```
0|Init|0|20|0||00|
1|Noop|0|0|0||00|
2|OpenRead|0|2|0|4|00|
3|OpenRead|2|4|0|k(4,nil,nil,nil,nil)|00|
4|Last|2|17|1|0|00|
5|IdxRowid|2|1|0||00|
6|Seek|0|1|0||00|
7|Column|2|1|2||00|
8|Ne|3|16|2|(BINARY)|54|
9|Column|2|2|4||00|
10|Ne|3|16|4|(BINARY)|54|
11|Column|0|0|5||00|
12|Copy|4|6|0||00|
13|Copy|2|7|0||00|
14|Column|2|0|8||00|
15|ResultRow|5|4|0||00|
16|Prev|2|5|0||01|
17|Close|0|0|0||00|
18|Close|2|0|0||00|
19|Halt|0|0|0||00|
20|Transaction|0|0|2|0|01|
21|TableLock|0|2|0|Shares|00|
22|Integer|3|3|0||00|
23|Goto|0|1|0||00|
```

It seems the query use the index to finish the job. But I don't know whether it uses all three index or just use time to do the index.
I hope the indices could be all used to give the performance enhancement.

Answer (score 3):

To find out how the query is executed, don't use EXPLAIN but [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html):

```
explain query plan select * from Shares where toId=3 and fromId=3 order by time desc;
0|0|0|SCAN TABLE Shares USING INDEX Shares_time_toId_fromId
```

In this query, the `toId` and `fromId` values are read from the index, but this does not matter because the actual table has to be read anyway to get the `shareId` value.

If the query did not try to read the `shareId` column, or if the `shareId` column had type `INTEGER` so that it would be an alias for the [rowid](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid) and thus be part of the index, the separate table lookup step would not be needed.

(Note: the [latest](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html) version of the `sqlite3` tool formats the EXPLAIN output better.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I change the primary key to a separate `id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` and `shareId TEXT NOT NULL`. Would this be effective to fetch the rowid?

Comment: Would `shareId` then be part of the index?

Comment: No. As I thought the query use `time` `toId` `fromId` to get the Index entry. And then use the rowid within the Index to locate the whole row in the database. So the shareId could not be part of the index. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. (You could add `shareId` to the index; but measure.)